# How to draw lines across datapoints of an existing D3 Chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, svg, charts

I am working on a D3 Chart that looks like this:

[image]

Fair warning: I am very new to D3. What I need to do now is to connect all datapoints across the z-axis with a line. So for all ages I want a line that starts at z = 0 and finishes at z = 4, that passes through all spheres, where z represents Capital Type. The end goal is to have a chart that resembles a surface area plot. I have looked at how to draw lines on D3 but I keep getting very generic things:

```
//Make an SVG Container
var svgContainer = d3.select("body").append("svg")
.attr("width", 200)
.attr("height", 200);

//Draw the line
var circle = svgContainer.append("line")
.attr("x1", 5)
.attr("y1", 5)
.attr("x2", 50)
.attr("y2", 50);
```

What I need is a way to loop through all my datapoints and draw lines between them. This is how I declare my datapoints variables (`var datapoints` represents the vertical lines alone and `var newDataPoints` represents the blue spheres on top of each one:

```
var datapoints = scene.selectAll(".datapoint").data( rows );
datapoints.exit().remove()

var newDatapoints = datapoints.enter()
.append("transform")
.attr("class", "datapoint")
.attr("scale", [sphereRadius, sphereRadius, sphereRadius])
.append("shape");
newDatapoints
.append("appearance")
.append("material");
newDatapoints
.append("sphere")`
```

Thanks in advance for any help!